# Apache + PHP customize $_SERVER superglobal

Tags: php, apache

I want to modify my Apache server to exclude most of the values it populates in the `$_SERVER` superglobal. The reason for this is that I am not using any of those except for HTTP prefixed headers, maybe CONTENT_LENGTH and possibly a couple more.

I see no need for the server to parse this data on every request when it is never going to be used by my particular application.

How can I manage (enable/disable) values that apache fills into `$_SERVER`?

Comment: Don't worry about it. _You_ don't have to parse anything. Let Apache/PHP do their job, you have enough to worry about building your app without trying to tell Apache/PHP how to setup the `$_SERVER` array.

Comment: @jszobody _I_ don't have to, but the server has to. This is wastage of resources, theoretically.

Comment: Off topic. You should rather ask this on http://www.serverfault.com next time. SO is aimed at programming questions, not questions of programmers which happen to be Ops as well. Flagged for moving.

Comment: The waste of resources is negligible. You could as well say that using a scripting language like PHP is a wast of resources compared to a native CGI application.